# Yoast SEO shows " No images appear on this page "

Tags: seo, images, yoast

Yoast SEO shows "  No images appear on this page " for a particular page which contains images in my website.
I already updated Yoast SEO plugin, but there is no change.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Yoast only seems to pick up images that are either on the theme's Featured Image function or in the default post editor content itself.

You haven't included a link to your website. My own website relies heavily on Advanced Custom Fields and PHP functions/shortcodes that produce images, and Yoast doesn't always pick these up.

Presumably, because they're not rendered on WP-admin therefore Yoast doesn't see them.